# Nautilus multicolumn list view

Tags: nautilus

I'm trying to get Nautilus to display files in a list view across multiple columns, like is seen in the image below, and I just can't find how to do it.

[image: Compact icons]

Source: https://blogs.gnome.org/cneumair/files/2008/02/screenshot-compact-icons.png

Here are the versions of Ubuntu and Nautilus I'm using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

GNOME nautilus 3.26.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not overlook anything. Unfortunately, such view is not anymore supported in Files, a.k.a. nautilus. The two available views are the icon view, where files are ordered from left to right, and column view, where files are ordered in a single column.

Comment: *Googles Nautilus alternatives*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unacceptable regression in Nautilus. Can't even find a parameter for compact list view buried somewhere in dconf editor. Thankfully I am a Xubuntu user; Xubuntu comes with the Thunar file manager.

My recommendation is to install Thunar and be happy! It has icon, detailed list, and yes, compact list views. Also take a look at Thunar's *Configure custom actions*, another feature Nautilus cannot compete with. Makes it super easy to add right-click menu items.