# Compact view on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nautilus, 20.04, filemanager

I'm looking for a way (anything it's ok) to set compact view on Ubuntu 20.04; the important thing is that the other options I set in Nautilus remain unchanged.

The above question is different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250156/adding-compact-view-option-to-nautilus-on-ubuntu-19-10) because is not only related to nautilus.

---

EDIT: example in the below screenshot. Morevorer, when I right click on a region where there aren't names, the menù (new folder...) opens, not the menu of the file which is on the left of the area where I clicked.

[image]

Comment: Rather than make a duplicate post, please see my answer here
https://askubuntu.com/a/1338739/1257260

Comment: It seems like using an alternative File Manager like Thunar is the only solution for now. Does it give you what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Nautilus has two views, a list view showing details about the files, and an icon view that shows icon and file name only. In either view, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, and you see the icons can be decreased to a really small size, rendering the view quite compact.

Comment: Hello @vanadium, I need a compact view as in Windows

Comment: I do not know Windows. Clarify your question (use "edit"). Just mentioning "as in WIndows" is not enough information.

Comment: Hi @vanadium I edited my question (the screnshot is about windows 7, but it's the same in windows 10). The difference between ubuntu and windows is that in ubunt, to see the files that doesn't enter in the page you need to scroll down, instead in windows you can see them on the right column (if the names are not too long)